# When is using an iterator appropriate?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm currently taking a class on data structures (in c++) and today we briefly touched iterators.  The prof didn't really make much sense of it and while i acquired a basic understanding of what iterators do I was wondering if someone could expand on the topic, possibly giving a Pro's/Con's list of using them vs not preferably in c++ but a general outline would also work.

Thanks in advance to everyone who responds :).

Comment: I think the question is actually very clear.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - the question was put on hold for being off-topic, not unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the specific reason it's off-topic is (supposedly) that it doesn't "describe the specific problem". How do you suggest that the OP should be explaining a "specific problem" when it comes to a choice of iterator or "not using iterator"? Or can't you ask questions that are "When should I use X?" type questions?

Comment: I voted to close, but was struggling with finding the best fitting reason. Basically the answer boils down to "use an iterator when iterating". Often, there is no alternative. Pros: Makes it possible to iterate. The question is unclear: Which alternative are we comparing against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an iterator can maintain the protected status of object data. For example, you will probably be iterating through a list. An iterator returned could allow you to step through the list elements (nodes) without being able to directly modify the list. It's implementation dependent, though. You could easily write your own iterator that allows direct modification of the list vectors. It's just another form of convenience abstraction.

An iterator as an interface (pure abstract) could be used to provide a common interface to iterate through different types of lists or arrays, as they are in Java, C#, etc.